# For loop with multiple conditions and ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro VBA project. I am currently stuck at a For loop function. I have 5 different ranges (Range O, P, Q, S, T) and the results of ranges P, Q, S, T depend on the value of Range O. After running the code, I got an error saying "Type mismatch" but I can't seem to figure out where is my mistake. Hope anyone can help me with an idea or resolution. Thank you very much :)

***The error starts at the second last ElseIf line*

My current code:-

```vb
Sub TestSort()
        '
        ' TestSort Macro
        '
        Dim r As Long
        lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = Range("O2:O" & lastrow)
        Set rng2 = Range("P2:P" & lastrow)
        Set rng3 = Range("Q2:Q" & lastrow)
        Set rng4 = Range("S2:S" & lastrow)
        Set rng5 = Range("T2:T" & lastrow)
    
        For r = 1 To lastrow
            If rng1.Cells(r) = "PCR" And rng2.Cells(r) = "ND" Then
                rng2.Cells(r) = "Coronavirus (COVID-19) Not Detected"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antigen Test" And rng2.Cells(r) = "ND" Then
                rng3.Cells(r) = "Negative"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antigen Test" And rng2.Cells(r) = "DET" Then
                rng3.Cells(r) = "Positive"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antibodi Test (Separate) M" And rng2.Cells(r) = "ND" Then
                rng4.Cells(r) = "Negative" And rng5.Cells(r) = "Positive"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antibodi Test (Separate) M" And rng2.Cells(r) = "DET" Then
                rng4.Cells(r) = "Positive" And rng5.Cells(r) = "Negative"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antibodi Test (Separate) G" And rng2.Cells(r) = "ND" Then
                rng5.Cells(r) = "Negative" And rng4.Cells(r) = "Positive"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antibodi Test (Separate) G" And rng2.Cells(r) = "DET" Then
                rng5.Cells(r) = "Positive" And rng4.Cells(r) = "Negative"
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where in the code is the error flagging? Also remember to set the range property `Value` - which is better, i.e. `rng1.Cells(r).Value = "PCR"`. Also when setting your values break it up over two lines of code.

Comment: Hi Dean, sorry I have edited my post to state the error in the code. Yes, I have tried setting the range property 'Value' and it is working correctly too. This is a new lesson for me! TQVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure the issue is the `And` in the assigning values to the sheet.

```
Sub TestSort()
        '
        ' TestSort Macro
        '
        Dim r As Long
        lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = Range("O2:O" & lastrow)
        Set rng2 = Range("P2:P" & lastrow)
        Set rng3 = Range("Q2:Q" & lastrow)
        Set rng4 = Range("S2:S" & lastrow)
        Set rng5 = Range("T2:T" & lastrow)
    
        For r = 1 To lastrow
            If rng1.Cells(r) = "PCR" And rng2.Cells(r) = "ND" Then
                rng2.Cells(r) = "Coronavirus (COVID-19) Not Detected"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antigen Test" And rng2.Cells(r) = "ND" Then
                rng3.Cells(r) = "Negative"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antigen Test" And rng2.Cells(r) = "DET" Then
                rng3.Cells(r) = "Positive"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antibodi Test (Separate) M" And rng2.Cells(r) = "ND" Then
                rng4.Cells(r) = "Negative"
                rng5.Cells(r) = "Positive"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antibodi Test (Separate) M" And rng2.Cells(r) = "DET" Then
                rng4.Cells(r) = "Positive" 
                rng5.Cells(r) = "Negative"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antibodi Test (Separate) G" And rng2.Cells(r) = "ND" Then
                rng5.Cells(r) = "Negative"
                rng4.Cells(r) = "Positive"
            ElseIf rng1.Cells(r) = "Rapid Antibodi Test (Separate) G" And rng2.Cells(r) = "DET" Then
                rng5.Cells(r) = "Positive"
                rng4.Cells(r) = "Negative"
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```